# How to remove persistent favorite from KDE Menu in Plasma 5.x?

Tags: kde, menu, plasma

I have a problem with the KDE Plasma Menu. The **favorite applications** section has a "kate app" icon, and I removed it from favorites, but when I restart, the icon is still there.

I don't know where the config file for favorites is, or how I can remove that shortcut permanently. KDE menu editor doesn't manage favorite apps, so I don't think that can help me.

UPDATE: after search for "kate" in home directory i got this:

```
grep -rnw '~' -e 'kate'
```

> ./.xsession-errors:2427:[KASTATSFAVS]  0x38021d0 0x382ce90
>   "org.kde.plasma.kicker.favorites.instance-20"   removeFavorite
>   "org.kde.kate.desktop"  -->
>
> ./.xsession-errors:2428:[KASTATSFAVS]     0x38021d0 0x382ce90
>   "org.kde.plasma.kicker.favorites.instance-20"      removeFavoriteFrom
>   "org.kde.kate.desktop" ":any"  -->
>
> ./.xsession-errors:2429:Original id is:  "org.kde.kate.desktop" , and 
>   the url is
>   QUrl("file:///usr/share/applications/org.kde.kate.desktop")
>
> ./.xsession-errors:2430:[KASTATSFAVS]  0x38021d0 0x382ce90
>   "org.kde.plasma.kicker.favorites.instance-20"   addFavoriteTo
>   "org.kde.kate.desktop" Activity:
>   (":any")"applications:org.kde.kate.desktop" (actual)
>
> ./.xsession-errors:2431:Unlink
>   "org.kde.plasma.favorites.applications"
>   QUrl("applications:org.kde.kate.desktop") ":any"
>
> ./.xsession-errors:2432:Original id is:
>   "applications:org.kde.kate.desktop" , and the url is
>   QUrl("file:///usr/share/applications/org.kde.kate.desktop")
>
> ./.xsession-errors:2433:[KASTATSFAVS]  0x38021d0 0x382ce90
>   "org.kde.plasma.kicker.favorites.instance-20"   Removing result
>   "applications:org.kde.kate.desktop"
>
> ./.xsession-errors:2434:Original  id is: 
>   "applications:org.kde.kate.desktop" , and the url is
>   QUrl("file:///usr/share/applications/org.kde.kate.desktop")
>
> ./.xsession-errors:3454:[KASTATSFAVS]  0x2d508c0 0x2dec620
>   "org.kde.plasma.kicker.favorites.instance-20"   Got
>   "org.kde.kate.desktop"  -->
>
> ./.xsession-errors:3455:[KASTATSFAVS]     0x2d508c0 0x2dec620
>   "org.kde.plasma.kicker.favorites.instance-20"      Adding result
>   "org.kde.kate.desktop" already present? false
>
> ./.xsession-errors:3456:Original id is:  "org.kde.kate.desktop" , and 
>   the url is
>   QUrl("file:///usr/share/applications/org.kde.kate.desktop")
>
> ./.xsession-errors:3461:[KASTATSFAVS]  0x2d508c0 0x2dec620
>   "org.kde.plasma.kicker.favorites.instance-20"   After ordering:
>   QVector("applications:systemsettings.desktop",
>   "applications:rhythmbox.desktop",
>   "applications:org.kde.kate.desktop")
>
> ./.xsession-errors:4040:[KASTATSFAVS]  0x3d02e50 0x3d25280
>   "org.kde.plasma.kicker.favorites.instance-20"   Got
>   "org.kde.kate.desktop"  -->
>
> ./.xsession-errors:4041:[KASTATSFAVS]     0x3d02e50 0x3d25280
>   "org.kde.plasma.kicker.favorites.instance-20"      Adding result
>   "org.kde.kate.desktop" already present? false
>
> ./.xsession-errors:4042:Original id is:  "org.kde.kate.desktop" , and 
>   the url is
>   QUrl("file:///usr/share/applications/org.kde.kate.desktop")
>
> ./.xsession-errors:4047:[KASTATSFAVS]  0x3d02e50 0x3d25280
>   "org.kde.plasma.kicker.favorites.instance-20"   After ordering:
>   QVector("applications:systemsettings.desktop",
>   "applications:rhythmbox.desktop",
>   "applications:org.kde.kate.desktop")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is almost guaranteed to be [this bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=385814).  TL;DR: it was fixed sometime in June of 2020, after first being reported in 2017.

The short and sweet solution, probably still required even after plasma upgrades:

```
$ sqlite3 ~/.local/share/kactivitymanagerd/resources/database
sqlite> DELETE from ResourceLink where targettedResource='kate.desktop';
sqlite> DELETE from ResourceLink where targettedResource='org.kde.kate.desktop';
```

Change we'll be applied next time you login again.

Comment: you right, now the icon is gone..
(after have kate uninstalled, i installed it, and with my os updated, there is no more bug)

Comment: I was able to take this approach to fix LibreOffice: `SELECT * FROM ResourceLink WHERE targettedResource='libreoffice-startcenter.desktop';`.

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the following:

```
~/.config/kactivitymanagerd-statsrc
~/.local/share/kactivitymanagerd/
```

After that, logoff or reboot. Simply restarting plasma may not be sufficient. You'll loose all favorites, but can recreate them by adding what you want.

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is in `~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc`.

Comment: the favorites  apps do not appear here

Answer (score 0):

Until we got a definitive solution you can try this:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/org.kde.kate.desktop
```

Comment: thanks!.. but that "patch" will delete it from application menu too (not only favorites) or not?

Comment: Yes, you're right. However, you can continue using the application by typing its name in the launcher and selecting "run kate". This removal will automatically be rolled back until at least the next application update.

Comment: i delete it from /usr/share/applications/ 
.. but it reapears after reboots!!!

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be still there in Plasma 5.12. In my case, it was the libreoffice-startcenter.desktop that kept reappearing in the kicker menu even after I removed that entry from every config file I could find in the user directory. The only solution that seems to work is to nuke the corresponding .desktop file from /usr/share/applications folder.

Comment: This solution was able to remove LibreOffice for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/1262035/496857